# How can I assign Boolean Value true or false to the string "Open" and "Close"

Tags: java

So I have this code but I can't figure out the following:

1. Why does the output stop at 99? I know I set boolean[100] and I changed it to 101 but that didn't work.
2. How can I get the output to print "Locker x is open" or "Locker x is closed"? I know I have to somehow assign boolean `true` to open and `false` to closed.

Please help thanks!

### Code

```
public class lockerPuzzle{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100];
        for(int i = 1; i < lockers.length; i++){
            for (int j = i; j < lockers.length; j+=i){
                if (lockers[j] == false){
                    lockers[j] = true;
                }
                else{
                    lockers[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1; i <lockers.length; i++){
            System.out.println(lockers[i] + " " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Array`'s are zero indexed, so an `Array` will 100 elements will have the index's `0-99`

Comment: More after @GBlodgett's comment: this is why you should start your loop with 0 as the initial value and not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why does the output stop at 99?

You started at index 1, when you should have started at index 0.

#### Difference

1-99 (99 elements)

0-99 (100 elements)

#### Code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i++){
        for (int j = i; j < lockers.length; j+=i){
            if (lockers[j] == false){
                lockers[j] = true;
            }
            else{
                lockers[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <lockers.length; i++){
        System.out.println(lockers[i] + " " + i);
    }
}
```

## How can I get the output to print Locker x is open or closed?

You can check the truth value of the boolean and print some text based on its value:

```
public class lockerPuzzle{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // ...

        for(int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i++){
            boolean isOpened = lockers[i]

            if (isOpened) {
                System.out.println("Locker " + i + " is opened!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Locker " + i + " is closed!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This can be much more concise using more variables or ternary operators, but this will do for a new programmer. Good luck.

Comment: Don't forget the second `for` loop.

Comment: @MehdeeAhmed No problem brother. The road ahead as a programmer is tough, but you simply must keep going. Problems are normal to encounter. Embrace it ;) I also added more details as to the concise answers below on functional programming. Eventually you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting index from 1, Which will skip the first item in the Array. I have simplified your code here is the code, You don't really need those if statements

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean[] lockers = new boolean[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i++){
        for (int j = i; j < lockers.length; j+=i){
            lockers[j] = !lockers[j];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <lockers.length; i++){
        System.out.println(lockers[i] + " " + i);
    }
}
```